# No sound via HDMI Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, pavucontrol

I'm not getting any sound via HDMI. Video on HDMI and sound on Laptop speakers are working fine.

The soundcard is recognized by alsa

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

(I assume HDMI output is the last one, so 0,3)

and I'm able to select the according device both in the system settings and in pavucontrol, it isn't muted (it's called "HDMI / DisplayPort" there).

Nothing is muted in alsamixer either, but I'm not sure which device it actually is:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.1.9 ───────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                                                   F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Realtek Generic                                                                 F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All                                              F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: -14,25]                                                        Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                                                               │
│                                                                                                               │
│                                                                                                               │
│    ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐                                                   ┌──┐    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │  │       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │  │    │
│    │▒▒│       │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │  │                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                                                   │▒▒│    │
│    ├──┤       ├──┤       ├──┤       └──┘       └──┘       ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐     Disabled     └──┘    │
│    │OO│       │OO│       │OO│                             │OO│       │OO│       │OO│                          │
│    └──┘       └──┘       └──┘                             └──┘       └──┘       └──┘                          │
│     54       46<>46    100<>100   100<>100    22<>22                                                 53<>53   │
│<  Master  >Headphone   Speaker      PCM     Mic Boost    S/PDIF   S/PDIF Def S/PDIF 16  Auto-Mute  Internal M │
│                                                                                                               │
│                                                                                                               │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

When switching to HDMI the laptop speakers are deactivated and the meter in pavucontrol reflects what's currently being played. So in theory everything's recognized and working fine, I'm just not actually getting any sound. Same setup works on Windows though, so it's not a hardware issue.

Any ideas?